# Java 11 time - is (long)timestamp today

Tags: java, java-time

I have a cronjob string saved in a mongo document field. I get the next valid (long)time by

```
CronExpression exp = new CronExpression(billing.getReminder());
            
long nextReminder = exp.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date()).getTime();
```

My idea is to check if this "nextReminder" isToday() then create  some task.
What is the best way to check it with java 11?

Comment: What is `nextReminder` ? Is it a standard millisecond timestamp?

Comment: Use `java.time`

Comment: Do you have some example data for validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `java.time` for a comparison...

There is an `Instant` representing a moment in time like a timestamp in epoch milliseconds does (⇒ your `long nextReminder`) as well as `OffsetDateTime.now()` for the actual moment *now* and `LocalDate` as the part describing the date-part only.

You could find out if the `nextReminder` is *today* by using a method like this:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Checks if the day (or date) of a given timestamp (in epoch milliseconds)
 * is the same as <em>today</em> (the day this method is executed).<br>
 * <strong>Requires an offset in order to have a common base for comparison</strong>
 * </p>
 *
 * @param epochMillis   the timestamp in epoch milliseconds to be checked
 * @param zoneOffset    the offset to be used as base of the comparison
 * @return <code>true</code> if the dates of the parameter and today are equal,
 *         otherwise <code>false</code>
 */
public static boolean isToday(long epochMillis, ZoneOffset zoneOffset) {
    // extract the date part from the parameter with respect to the given offset
    LocalDate datePassed = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis)
                                .atOffset(zoneOffset)
                                .toLocalDate();
    // then extract the date part of "now" with respect to the given offset
    LocalDate today = Instant.now()
                                .atOffset(zoneOffset)
                                .toLocalDate();
    // then return the result of an equality check
    return datePassed.equals(today);
}
```

and then just call it like

```
boolean isNextReminderToday = isToday(nextReminder, ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
```

which would use the time offset of the system. Maybe, `ZoneOffset.UTC` could be a smart choice, too.

Comment: I would think that any zone would be fine as long as both are corrected to the same one.  So why pass a zone at all?

Comment: @WJS yes, I think you're right. But this example clearly points out that a zone correction should be done to avoid edge cases. Could both be corrected to UTC, sure...

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63468862/10819573) is correct. However, I felt to write this one because in this case, using the Zone ID (instead of Zone Offset) makes the code a bit simpler and also easier to understand.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A test data
        long nextReminder = 1597754387710L;

        // Your time-zone e.g. Europe/London
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        // Next reminder date
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(nextReminder);
        LocalDate nextReminderDate = instant.atZone(zoneId).toLocalDate();

        // Today at the time-zone of Europe/London
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zoneId);

        if (today.equals(nextReminderDate)) {
            System.out.println("The next reminder day is today");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The next reminder day is today
```

Comment: To me, it doesn't make a huge difference, but it's good to have both ways as answers to a single question! It's important to use `java.time`...

Answer (score 1):

Using apache commons `DateUtils.isToday(nextReminder)`

Using your own method.

```java
private static final long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 86400000;

public static boolean isToday(long timestamp) {
   long now =  System.currentTimeMillis();
   long today = now.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
   long expectedDay = timestamp / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
   return today == expectedDay;
}
```

Note: Consider using UTC when working with date/time.

Comment: **Don't** use `Date` and `Calendar`. Use `java.time`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Absolute agree `java.time` is better than Calendar but don't agree you must use it always, believe me there are sometime more creative way doing one thing.
If it was the case both Date and Calendar would have been entirely deprecated.

Comment: @TraychoIvanov - `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` etc. should be never used if you are going to write new code. Check https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html to learn more about it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash If I target performance `java.time` is not fastest way, it is incorporating on joda-time in java spec. All issues with date were clear but if I have a specific question and  there is more than one choice I would abstain of words like never and always.

Comment: @TraychoIvanov - Your code, your choice. I can only recommend the best practice but in the end, it's your choice whether you implement it or not.